# Nice serverfault image

Tags: discussion, fun

Here's how splattne's announcement rendered in my browser... I thought it was quite appropriate!

[removed broken image link]

Comment: .                            Epic

Comment: I guess it's not my faul [sic]. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It's the server's fault!

Comment: I see what you did there!